# Different order of insertion - different Bayesian network ? how to prove formally?

Tags: bayesian, bayesian-network, artificial-intelligence, data-mining

I have some Bayesian network which i constructed from some data, say it consists of nodes `A, B, C and D` and that was the **initial order of insertion**.

If i reconstruct the network by **inserting the nodes in a different order** i will get a **different** structure which will represent the **same data** and with dependencies (arrows) which are different from the ones in the original network (also almost probably).

How to **formally** prove that different order of insertion leads to a different structure of a Beyesian network ? Is there some property such proof can be based on ? How can it be proved ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, have a look at the basic connections $A\rightarrow B\rightarrow C$ (serial),
$A\leftarrow B\leftarrow C$ (serial) and $A\leftarrow B\rightarrow C$ (diverging). They all give rise to the same joint probability distribution. But the converging connection $A\rightarrow B\leftarrow C$ is different.